# Matrix in latex using border matrix

Tags: overleaf, bordermatrix

I have written this in latex:

```
\begin {equation}
\label{E:1}
A={\frac{w_i}{w_j}} = {a_{ij}} ={\bbordermatrix{& C_1     & C_2     & C_\ldots & C_n \cr
    C_1     & (w_1/w_1)=1     & (w_1/w_2)=a_{12}     & \ldots & (w_1/w_n)=a_{1n} \cr
    C_2     & (w_2/w_1)=1/a_{12}     & (w_2/w_2)=1     & \ldots & (w_2/w_n)=a_{2n} \cr
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
    C_n     & (w_n/w_1)=1/a_{1n}     & (w_n/w_2)=1/a_{2n}     & \ldots  & (w_n/w_n)=1 \cr}}
\end {equation}
```

And I found this:

> Missing { inserted.
>
> Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ) must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ … $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.
>
> Learn more
>    
>   \mathinner 
>   l.393 ...)=1/a_{2n}     & \ldots  & (w_n/w_n)=1 \cr}
>                                                     }
>   A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
>   You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
>   so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
>   If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.
>
> ! Missing } inserted.
>    
>   }
>   l.393 ...)=1/a_{2n}     & \ldots  & (w_n/w_n)=1 \cr}
>                                                     }
>   I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
>   the current column of the current alignment.
>   Try to go on, since this might almost work.
>
> *I have tried to find this problem, but I couldn't find anything.*

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `\ldots` inside the `{}` in the first row and you should be good to go.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin {equation}
    \label{E:1}
    A={\frac{w_i}{w_j}} = {a_{ij}} =\bordermatrix{~ & C_1     & C_2     & C_{\ldots} & C_n \cr
    C_1     & (w_1/w_1)=1     & (w_1/w_2)=a_{12}     & \ldots & (w_1/w_n)=a_{1n} \cr    
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
C_n     & (w_n/w_1)=1/a_{1n}     & (w_n/w_2)=1/a_{2n}     & \ldots  & (w_n/w_n)=1 \cr}
    \end {equation}
\end{document}
```

this is what you would get out of it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Raaja. It works. You saved me. Cheers

Comment: @Valdo if you find it useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi Raaja, I have checked your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For information, here is a way to construct that matrix with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
A = \frac{w_i}{w_j} = a_{ij} =
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row]
& C_1     & C_2     & C_{\ldots} & C_n \\
C_1     & (w_1/w_1)=1     & (w_1/w_2)=a_{12}     & \ldots & (w_1/w_n)=a_{1n} \\
\Vdots[shorten=6pt] & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C_n     & (w_n/w_1)=1/a_{1n}     & (w_n/w_2)=1/a_{2n}     & \ldots  & (w_n/w_n)=1 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]